# SFSafariViewController hides network activity indicator when pushed in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, safari, ios9, xcode7

While `SFSafariViewController` is loading, we need to indicate to the user a website is loading in the ViewController we've just pushed.

The simplest idea is to turn on the network activity indicator before pushing the new SFSafariViewController and to turn it off in the delegate method once we know the website has loaded. However. when the SFSafariViewController slides in the UINavigationController, it slides over the app, which is fine, but the network activity indicator is not turned on anymore.

No network activity indicator is visible, so we can't communicate to the user that a website is being loaded. We need a way to communicate to the user that a website is being loaded in SFSafariViewController.

**I think it's a bug! of iOS 9.**

If anybody faced the same issue please tell me how to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

The progress view in the SFSafariViewController is the indicator for a user to know that a website is loading and that is already built in, why would you need another one? If the progress view is hidden because you're pushing add this line to your code, so that you hide the navigation bar: 
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;